# For graduate admissions, are difficult classes valued over perfect grades?

Tags: graduate-admissions, mathematics, grades

I am an undergrad at a top 5 research institution for context, and this is pertaining to math Ph.D. admissions.

I know looking at grades in isolation w.r.t. admissions is a questionable thing to do in the first place, but from an admissions perspective, are difficult classes valued over perfect grades? I guess the example in mind would be, is it better to have a couple of difficult courses + mostly undergrad courses with all As, or a lot of difficult classes but some Bs sprinkled in?

Comment: "Is it commonly believed that graduate classes are free A grades?" - No. If that's the case, either the person in question is unusually smart or the course is poorly assessed.

Comment: Doing well in graduate classes is _much_ more likely to lead to useful letters of recommendation than getting perfect grades in undergrad classes.

Comment: To be honest, you should be worrying about trying to get something published on Arxiv, since that will boost your chances way more than most grades.

Comment: @Leonpalafox On that, most professors I've talked to do not value publication in itself, but I am working on a project as I realize it would be good for my mathematical development, rec letters, signals interest and some level of knowledge about research, and such.

Comment: That's odd, usually graduate school admission committees put a lot of care on your capability to do research, which is the reason many students in natural sciences take one extra year just to beef up the resume with some publication. And as far as I know, even for computer science that is the case.

Comment: Right, but I think math is the exception as the amount of background it takes to produce research that people are interested in is far greater than what most undergrads have, for most fields.

Comment: _most professors I've talked to do not value publication in itself_ — Clearly, you talk to a different set of math professors than I do.

Comment: _far greater than what most undergrads have, for most fields_ — But you're not most undergrads, are you?

Comment: @JeffE I know what you're saying, and I think you probably know what I'm saying? This summer I'm working on moduli spaces for example, but my algebraic geometry is not at the point where I'm going to be producing any kind of outstandingly impressive result, and the same is true for all but perhaps a few undergrads countable with two hands, maybe one. It is certainly the case that there are many many more spots at top Ph.D. programs than there are people who are able to produce significant results as undergrads.

Comment: The point is not to produce "any kind of outstandingly impressive result".  The point is to produce, and then publish, **a result**.

Comment: We're on the same page, sort of. Professors have told me it's good to have some experience doing "research".

Comment: @JeffE: As a math professor working in areas close to that of the OP (my thesis was on a kind of moduli space), I somewhat disagree with what you're saying.  In many ways I think this discussion is more interesting than the question asked by the OP (though I don't see what was wrong with it and have voted to reopen).  Maybe we could open a new question on this point?

Comment: For one thing, when the OP says that "most professors I've talked to do not value publication in itself", he surely means that in the context of undergraduate students.  I agree with that: there are a lot of REUs these days, and a positive proportion of math grad school applicants have published **a result**.  Having done so is positively correlated with their admittance to the top programs...but the correlation is very far from perfect, and publishing **a result** is far from a golden ticket to admission at UGA, let alone Harvard.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I thought this was a very good discussion on undergrad research: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11113/how-important-are-publications-for-undergrads

Comment: @anonymous: Good find, that's a valuable discussion.  (I even participated in it...) I think it's a pretty good defense of the point I was making, and it makes me less interested in reopening that can of worms here.  On the other hand, that was four years ago, and I do think that things are slowly changing in the direction of increased undergraduate publication, so in another 5 years or so I think it would be worth checking in just to make sure we all still feel the same way.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a pretty easy one.

> I know looking at grades in isolation w.r.t. admissions is a questionable thing to do in the first place, but from an admissions perspective, are difficult classes valued over perfect grades?

Yes.

> I guess the example in mind would be, is it better to have a couple of difficult courses + mostly undergrad courses with all As, or a lot of difficult classes but some Bs sprinkled in?

The latter is distinctly better.  I got a B in the first graduate course I took as an undergraduate.  (I then took 8 more graduate courses and got A's.)  This did not stop me from getting into all the math PhD programs to which I applied, including the top three in the US.

Comment: I feel like a single B (or multiple) early on is not so bad though, I have a friend who just got into Princeton who had terrible grades freshman year, and another friend who got a C in a math class who got into several top programs. At what point (proportion of B grades) do you think the situation changes, out of curiosity? I suppose in terms of numbers I am thinking ~4 grad classes vs 8-10, in the first 3 years of undergrad.

Comment: @anonymous: Thanks, I agree that my undergraduate transcript was not so bad!  (Actually my GPA was about 3.95.)  I wouldn't feel confident specifying a threshhold percentage of B grades; that is so variable and depends on just about everything, including a specific applicant pool.  But I'll say that committees look for a trend towards increased success and increased mathematical understanding: if you do pretty well in one course then do excellently in later, more advanced courses, then the less than optimal earlier grade is allayed.  I specifically look for this when reading transcripts.